# UNITY CoRoutine and data synchronization with callback

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have to fetch many pictures from the internet, and show them next to the proper owners name. I have an array of textures, and their corresponding owners ID.

First I have to call an API function using the ID of the owner to get the URL of their picture, then fetch the picture at that URL.

So here is the c# unity pseudo code:

```
 void function() {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       start_fetch_url(picID[i],CallBack); // fetch URL of picID, via call back 
    }
 }

 // when url is received this is called, then fetch pic at that URL
 IEnumerator CallBack(string url)
 {
    WWW fetchPic= new WWW(url);
    while (fetchPic.isDone) {
      yeild return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
    }
    texture[????]=fetchPic.texture; '// <--- here is problem, which texture
 }
```

I cannot change the start_fetch_url API since I didnt write it and have no access to it.

start_fetch_url also access the internet to get the url based on the ID from a remote database.

Problems:
1. start_fetch_url returns the URL in random order to the call back function, so I cant tell which texture the url is for.

2. Maybe I have to wait for each URL synchronously one at a time, then I can know which texture its for, but how to write code for that?
3. Is there a way to not wait?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot change `start_fetch_url` and you cannot cannot infer the user id based on the `url` passed to your coroutine I think the only way of doing this is to download the images in sequence.

You can achieve this by keeping the user index in a class variable and only go to the next picture when your coroutine gets called.

```
var index = 0;

function load_next()
{
 //we've reached the end
 if( index == 10 )
 {
  return;
 }

 start_fetch_url(picID[i],CallBack);
}

// when url is received this is called, then fetch pic at that URL
IEnumerator CallBack(string url)
{
  WWW fetchPic= new WWW(url);

  while (fetchPic.isDone) 
  {
   yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.1f);
  }

  texture[index]=fetchPic.texture; 

  //continue with the fetching
  index++;
  load_next();
}
```

Note: you don't need to poll to check that the download has ended, you can just call `yield return fetchPic;`. If you need to show a progress bar then you need to use the while as it is now.